# IHealthCheckPublisher and SetEvaluationTimeInSeconds

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, health-check

We are using .NET 7, [AspNetCore.HealthChecks.UI 7.0.2](https://www.nuget.org/packages/AspNetCore.HealthChecks.UI/7.0.2) and [AspNetCore.HealthChecks.UI.Client 7.1.0](https://www.nuget.org/packages/AspNetCore.HealthChecks.UI.Client/7.1.0). We have the following code in `Startup.cs`:

```cs
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services
        .AddHealthChecks()
        .AddCheck<NotificationsServiceHealthCheck>("Notifications service health check", tags: new[] { "external-service" });

    var evaluationTimeInSeconds = 60;
    services.Configure<HealthCheckPublisherOptions>(options =>
    {
        options.Period = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(evaluationTimeInSeconds);
    });

    services.AddSingleton<IHealthCheckPublisher, CustomHealthCheckPublisher>();

    services
        .AddHealthChecksUI(setup =>
        {
            setup.AddHealthCheckEndpoint("External services health checks", "https://localhost:44366/health-external-services");
            setup.SetEvaluationTimeInSeconds(evaluationTimeInSeconds);
        })
        .AddPostgreSqlStorage("CONNECTION_STRING", c => c.UseNpgsql(o => o.MigrationsHistoryTable(HistoryRepository.DefaultTableName, "hangfire")));
}

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env, ILogger<Startup> logger)
{
    app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
    {
        endpoints.MapHealthChecks("/health-external-services", new HealthCheckOptions()
        {
            Predicate = r => r.Tags.Contains("external-service"),
            ResponseWriter = UIResponseWriter.WriteHealthCheckUIResponse
        });
        
        endpoints.MapHealthChecksUI(setup =>
        {
            setup.UIPath = "/HealthChecks";
            setup.AsideMenuOpened = false;
        });
    });
}
```

We registered custom implementation of `IHealthCheckPublisher` (`CustomHealthCheckPublisher`) which sends an email containing all failed health checks to system administrators.

```cs
public class CustomHealthCheckPublisher : IHealthCheckPublisher
{
    public Task PublishAsync(HealthReport report, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        if (report.Status == HealthStatus.Healthy)
        {
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }

        var nonhealthyChecks = report.Entries
            .Where(x => x.Value.Status != HealthStatus.Healthy)
            .ToList();

        // send email with 'nonhealthyChecks'

        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
```

We noticed that all health checks are run twice - once because of `options.Period = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(evaluationTimeInSeconds);` and once because of `setup.SetEvaluationTimeInSeconds(evaluationTimeInSeconds)`. This behavior of `IHealthCheckPublisher` is also documented [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/health-checks?view=aspnetcore-7.0#health-check-publisher) (*"If Predicate is null (default), the health check publisher service runs all registered health checks. To run a subset of health checks, provide a function that filters the set of checks. The predicate is evaluated each period."*). Moreover, we noticed that health check results are persisted to PostgreSQL database only when they are triggered by `SetEvaluationTimeInSeconds`.

How can we achieve that health checks are run only once per time interval, have their results stored in the database and invoking `CustomHealthCheckPublisher.PublishAsync` which sends an email witl all failed health checks? In essence, we need a "callback" which should be called with the final `HealthReport` when all health checks are evaluated (without re-evaluating them).

Answer (score -1):

You might need to do some changes in your startup.cs file to achieve your requirement. like remove the `HealthCheckPublisherOptions` configuration and rely solely on the `SetEvaluationTimeInSeconds` method within `AddHealthChecksUI` to trigger the health checks. This should ensure that health checks run only once per the specified interval, store their results in the database, and invoke your custom health check publisher as needed.

Startup.cs:

```
 public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services
        .AddHealthChecks()
        .AddCheck<NotificationsServiceHealthCheck>("Notifications service health check", tags: new[] { "external-service" });

    var evaluationTimeInSeconds = 60;

    services.AddSingleton<IHealthCheckPublisher, CustomHealthCheckPublisher>();

    services
        .AddHealthChecksUI(setup =>
        {
            setup.AddHealthCheckEndpoint("External services health checks", "https://localhost:44366/health-external-services");
            setup.SetEvaluationTimeInSeconds(evaluationTimeInSeconds);
        })
        .AddPostgreSqlStorage("CONNECTION_STRING", c => c.UseNpgsql(o => o.MigrationsHistoryTable(HistoryRepository.DefaultTableName, "hangfire")));
}

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env, ILogger<Startup> logger)
{
    // ... existing middleware 

    app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
    {
        endpoints.MapHealthChecks("/health-external-services", new HealthCheckOptions()
        {
            Predicate = r => r.Tags.Contains("external-service"),
            ResponseWriter = UIResponseWriter.WriteHealthCheckUIResponse
        });
        
        endpoints.MapHealthChecksUI();
    });
}
```

CustomHealthCheckPublisher:

```
public class CustomHealthCheckPublisher : IHealthCheckPublisher
{
    // Inject any dependencies you need, like a logger or an email service

    public CustomHealthCheckPublisher(/* Dependencies */)
    {
        // Assign the dependencies to local variables
    }

    public async Task PublishAsync(HealthReport report, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        if (report.Status == HealthStatus.Healthy)
        {
            // Log or handle healthy report
            return;
        }

        var nonhealthyChecks = report.Entries
            .Where(x => x.Value.Status != HealthStatus.Healthy)
            .Select(x => new { x.Key, x.Value.Status, x.Value.Description })
            .ToList();

        if (nonhealthyChecks.Any())
        {
            // Process non-healthy checks, e.g., send an email or log
            foreach (var check in nonhealthyChecks)
            {
                // Example: Log the details
                // _logger.LogError($"Health check failed: {check.Key} with status {check.Status}: {check.Description}");

                // Or send an email/notification
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Removing `services.Configure<HealthCheckPublisherOptions>` doesn't really do much. Documentation states that the default value of `Period` is 30 seconds ([source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.diagnostics.healthchecks.healthcheckpublisheroptions.period?view=dotnet-plat-ext-7.0)). `CustomHealthCheckPublisher` is still invoked every 30 seconds which results in all health checks being re-executed. They are still executed by both `CustomHealthCheckPublisher` and `SetEvaluationTimeInSeconds`.

Comment: @SamCarlson  You are right that removing the `services.Configure<HealthCheckPublisherOptions>` only changes the frequency to the default of 30 seconds. The `CustomHealthCheckPublisher` being invoked every 30 seconds leads to the health checks being executed twice: once by the health check publisher and once by the UI's `SetEvaluationTimeInSeconds`. To resolve this, you need to coordinate the execution so that only one of these mechanisms triggers the health checks. i have updated the answer according to your response.

Comment: 1) What is `HealthCheckService` in your example?
2) You call `CheckHealthAsync` inside `PublishAsync` which means that you re-execute health checks once more. The outcome is the same - health checks are executed by both `CustomHealthCheckPublisher` and UI's `SetEvaluationTimeInSeconds`.

Comment: made the changes according to the issue you mentioned now Health Checks UI is set to trigger health checks every `evaluationTimeInSeconds` and show the results and  `CustomHealthCheckPublisher` processes the health check results without re-triggering the checks.

Comment: Again: Before every invocation of `IHealthCheckPublisher.PublishAsync`, all health-checks are re-run. Default interval for `IHealthCheckPublisher.PublishAsync` invocation is 30 seconds. I verified this by setting `SetEvaluationTimeInSeconds=99999999` and omitted `options.Period = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(evaluationTimeInSeconds);`. Health checks were run every 30 seconds and `PublishAsync` was called after all health checks were run. As stated before, this is not what we want because `PublishAsync` doesn't store any results in the health checks database.

Comment: You can also verify this in the source code of `HealthCheckPublisherHostedService`. Inside the [`RunAsyncCore`](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/b98185b6376b966c5a051926986acaf204fe4e76/src/HealthChecks/HealthChecks/src/HealthCheckPublisherHostedService.cs#L192C9-L192C9), health checks are re-run first and after that `PublishAsync` is invoked.